# Collaborative filtering for news articles or blog posts

Tags: twitter, recommendation-engine, sparse-matrix, collaborative-filtering

It's known how collaborative filtering (CF) is used for movie, music, book recommendations. In the  paper '[Collaborative Topic Modeling for Recommending Scientiﬁc Articles](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chongw/papers/WangBlei2011.pdf)' among other things authors show an example of collaborative filtering applied to ~5,500 users and ~17,000 scientific articles. With ~200,000 user-item pairs, the user-article matrix is obviously highly sparse.

What if you do collaborative filtering with [matrix factorization](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/) for, say, all news articles shared on Twitter? The matrix will be even sparser (than that in the scientific articles case) which makes CF not very applicable. Of course, we can do some content-aware analysis (taking into account, the text of an article), but that's not my focus. Or we can potentially limit our time window (focus, say, on all news articles shared in the last day or week) to make the user-article matrix denser. Any other ideas how to fight the fact that the matrix is very sparse? What are the results in research in the area of CF for news article recommendations? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with sparse matrix? You mean that the matrix doesn't fit in memory or the results are inaccurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try using an object-to-object collaborative filter instead of a user-to-object filter. Age out related pairs (and low-incidence pairs) over time since they're largely irrelevant in your use case anyway.

I did some work on the Netflix Prize back in the day, and quickly found that I could significantly outperform the base model with regard to predicting which items were users' favorites. Unfortunately, since it's basically a rank model rather than a scalar predictor, I didn't have RMSE values to compare.

I know this method works because I wrote a production version of this same system. My early tests showed that, given a task wherein 50% of users' top-rated movies were deleted, the object-to-object model correctly predicted (i.e., "replaced") about 16x more of users' actual favorites than a basic slope-one model. Plus the table size is manageable. From there it's easy to include a profitability weight against the sort order, etc. depending on your application.

Hope this helps! I have a working version in production but am still looking for beta clients to bang on the system... if anyone has time to give it a run I'd love to hear from you.

Jeb Stone, PhD

[www.selloscope.com](http://www.selloscope.com)